# How to create a json object with input variable

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create a JSON object with input variable. I have a 2 input field. when I click button i want to take input values and make a JSON object with that value. I cannot create a JSON object with entered value.

I try that

```
//getting the value of input as a variable
let id=document.querySelector("#id");
let title=document.querySelector("#title");
```

first I try the below. it sends a blank value instead of variable string

```
var vObj= '{"id":'+id.value+',"title":'+title.value+'}'
```

I also try that to

```
var vObj = {"id":{},"v_title":{}, "v_category":{}};
vObj.id=id.value;
vObj.title=title.value;
```

tried that

```
let asd=id.value;
let bsd=title.value;

var vObj = {id:asd, title:bsd}
```

it returns a blank value instead of variable value.

i am making a mistake that the trigger button has typo. i couldn't see that. sorry

Comment: Are you sure 
document.querySelector("#id").value;
document.querySelector("#title").value;

is returning string value?

Comment: Do you really want to create **JSON** or a JavaScript object? What do you intend to do with `vObj`? The term "JSON object" is a misleading term so it needs clarification.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to change. i edit the question.

Comment: i need Json object to post rest api

Comment: So you really want to JSON. The answers you have received so far should help. Create an object and then use `JSON.stringify` to convert it to JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an object with name proeprties and then use `JSON.stringify` to turn this into valid JSON:

```js
//let id = document.querySelector("#id").value;
let id = 'my_id';
//let title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
let title = 'my_title';
console.log('ID: ' + id);
console.log('Title: ' + title);

var vObj = { id: id, title: title };
var json = JSON.stringify(vObj);
console.log(json);
```

This line:

```
var vObj = { id: id, title: title };
```

Creates an object with an `id` with the value of the `id` variable, and a `title` with the value of the `title` variable.

This line:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(vObj);
```

Converts the object `vObj` to a JSON string.

Output:

```
ID: my_id
Title: my_title
{"id":"my_id","title":"my_title"}
```

**Edit followimg @FelixKling comment**

In ES6 it is possible to simplify the declaration of `vObj` using:

```
var vObj = {id, title};
```

This will create the same object with the assumed property names `id` and `title`.  Obviously if your variable is not named `id` or `title` this will not work.

Comment: FWIW, this can be written as `var vobj = {id, title};` since ES6.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you, a good point. Presumably that is only in cases like this where the variable name matches the object property name?

Comment: That's right. The nice thing about it is that it can prevent typos (assuming of course the variable name is correct in the first place). E.g. `{titel: title}` vs `{title}`.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for confirming. I'll update the answer to reflect this useful change

Comment: i m sorry, if i want to get input value with a variable -not static value- it returns like that => { id: '', title: '' }

Comment: @AhuraMazda In which case the value of your variables is empty.  Try looking what's in them: `console.log(id);`

Comment: i got the blank value also. so i recognize a typo. i edit the question. thank you

Answer (score 1):

First create an object, then stringify it to JSON.

```
var jsonObj = JSON.stringify( { "id" : id, "title" : title } );
```

Comment: i cannot create an object with input variable value. it returns blank like { id: ' ', title: ' ' }

Comment: Then your problem isn't with creating the object, it's with populating the input variables.